# jQuery Deferred on Ajax is not passing array in data option as array but as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, jquery-deferred

In an application I want to use jQuery deferred to implement our Ajax success and error handling on a central place. Everything works great if I put strings in the data option, but if I want to put an array in the data option, it sends this as a string!

My deferred implementation:

```
Application = {
ajax: function(options) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred(function (d) {
        var defaults = {
            cache: false,
            type: 'post',
            traditional: true,
            dataType: 'json'
        },
        settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        d.done(settings.success);
        d.fail(settings.error);
        d.done(settings.complete);

        var jqXHRSettings = $.extend({}, settings, {
            success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                /*
                JSON Reponse
                {
                    status: 'error' or 'success',
                    code: 200, (HTTP codes or own codes between 600 and 700 for business logic errors)
                    data: { <result> }
                }
                */
                if (settings.dataType === 'json') {
                    if (response.status == 'success') {
                        // Just resolve and give data back
                        d.resolve(response.data);
                    } else if (response.status == 'error') {
                        // Implement error handling
                        d.reject(response.data);
                    }
                } else {
                    d.resolve(response);
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                d.reject(jqXHR);
            },
            complete: d.resolve
        });

        $.ajax(jqXHRSettings);
    });

    var promise = deferred.promise();
    promise.success = deferred.done;
    promise.error = deferred.fail;
    promise.complete = deferred.done;

    return promise;
}
};
```

My implementation of this deferred function (not working!):

```
// Retrieve all sessions from fullcalendars
        var ajax = Application.ajax({
            url: Routing.generate($this.options.ajaxScheduleSessionsRoute, { _format: 'json', id: this.options.scheduleId }),
            data: {
                "rooms": $this._rooms // $this._rooms is an array! [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
            }
        });
        ajax.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log(jqXHR);
        });
        ajax.done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            console.log(response);
        });
```

The result (missing the [])

[image: The result (missing the [])]

Default implementation of jQuery ajax before using above deferred function (this works!):

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: Routing.generate($this.options.ajaxScheduleSessionsRoute, { _format: 'json', id: this.options.scheduleId }),
            data: {
                "rooms": $this._rooms
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('status:' + XMLHttpRequest.status + ', status text: ' + XMLHttpRequest.statusText);
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function( key, source ) {
                    var roomId = key;
                    console.log(source);
                    $('#calendar'+key).fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', source );
                });
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
```

The result (with the [])

[image: The result (with the [])]

The question:
**Why is the default implementation with jQuery Ajax working and the deferred function is not?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh no, I submitted this question and afterwards I saw the traditional option in my deferred function :( I deleted it and it works great now. I could knew it was something stupid ;-)

So, dont use

```
var defaults = {
        cache: false,
        type: 'post',
        traditional: true,
        dataType: 'json'
    },
```

But use

```
var defaults = {
        cache: false,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json'
    },
```